# Joomla Version Control Selection

Tags: joomla

How to manage version control with joomla 3.0 ?
I tried Mod Version Control 30.100,versions,GENOVA Version Control.But no success.
Does anyone have idea about same?

Comment: please be a little more specific as to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming Joomla 3.2 should have Version Control natively - the alpha is available and general availability is planned for Oct 2013 - if you can wait a month before going live you might like to have a look at it :)

http://developer.joomla.org/news/566-joomla-3-2-alpha-released.html

Comment: Actually i just read about it.If i will use joomla 3 for now & update it to 3.2 later Is it ok?

Comment: That's entirely up to you to decide, but if the wait is possible, that's what I'd do! :)